# How does the Pauli Exclusion principle explain the incompressibility of metals?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, pauli-exclusion-principle, quantum-chemistry

The Pauli Exclusion principles states that no two identical fermions can have the same quantum state. In my lecture notes, it is mentioned that this principle helps us explain the fact that metals are very hard to compress. Why does this principle explain the incompressibity of metals?

Comment: More precisely the Pauli exclusion principle leads to a pressure called degeneracy pressure. This pressure is the one that counteracts the enormous gravitational forces in white dwarfs. So yes, it's pretty strong. A metal would break much before that because of breaking of chemical bonds.

Comment: @icv an equation of state governed by ideal electron degeneracy pressure is quite compressible.

Comment: Look up electron degeneracy pressure. As you try to force electrons in the metal into the same state, the an emergent 'pressure' arises due to the pauli principle.

Answer (score 4):

To rather a good approximation one may regard metal as Fermi-Liquid, the gas of non-interacting fermions. These obey the Fermi-statistic and the corresponding distribution is Fermi-Dirac:
$$
n(\varepsilon) = \frac{1}{e^{(\varepsilon - \mu) / T} + 1}
$$
For normal metals Fermi energy $\varepsilon_F = \mu$ is of order $\simeq 10^{4}$ K. Therefore, the energy distribution, plotted in units of $ \mu$ [[image: Fermi-Dirac distribution for various ratios <span class=]$T / \mu$">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfOTJ.png) for room temperatures of order $\simeq 10^{2}$ K is very close to step function.

Fermions occupy all states below the Fermi momentum $p_F$, with energy $< \varepsilon_F$. So the total energy of a system is:
$$
E = 2 \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3} \int d^3 k \ n(\varepsilon) \frac{\hbar k^2}{2m} = 
2 \frac{V}{(2 \pi)^3} \frac{2 \pi \hbar^2}{m} \int_{0}^{k_F} d k \ k^4 = 
\frac{V \hbar^2 k_F^5}{10 \pi^2 m} = 
\frac{V \hbar^2}{10 \pi^2 m} \left(3 \pi^2 \frac{N}{V}\right)^{5/3}
$$

Where 2 is a factor due to the presence of spin degeneracy. And in the last equality I have substituted the expression for Fermi momentum in 3D. The pressure is given by:
$$
P = -\frac{\partial E}{\partial V} = \frac{(3 \pi^2)^{2/3}}{5} 
\frac{\hbar^2}{m} \left( \frac{N}{V}\right)^{5/3} = \frac{2}{5} n \varepsilon_F
\qquad n = N / V
$$
The obtained value is rather large, as the concentration is number of order $n \simeq 10^{22}$ cm$^{-3}$, which gives the values of Young's modulus of order $10-100$ GPa.